# In ReactJs, How to dynamically change the Input type from "text" to "select"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have following code

```
                 <Controller
                  control={control}
                  name='part'
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <Input
                      type={(type === "fixed") ? "select" : "text"}
                      name="part"
                      className={errors.part && "is-invalid"}
                      value={field.value || ""}
                      onChange={(value) => field.onChange(value)}
                    >
                      //this code is causing error
                      {(type === "fixed") &&
                        partnOptions.map((opt) =>
                          <option value={opt.code} key={opt.code}>{opt.code}</option>
                        )
                      }
                    </Input>
                  )}
                />
```

And I got an error `input is a void element tag and must neither have children nor use dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which is understandable because I guess type `text` should not have any `children`. If I remove the `map` part it's working correctly, the `Input` field will change from `text` to `select` based on the `type` value. So, how do I include the `option` when the `Input` `type` is changed to `select`?

Comment: Are you sure `type={(type === "fixed") ? "select" : "text"}` is valid? Isn't there a separate `Select` component you can use?

Comment: There is no `<input type="select">` in HTML. You have render either an input (type text) or a select (with its option children).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using `reactstrap`, so `type='select'` is valid. I managed to achieve this by adding `: undefined` at the end

Answer (score 0):

In deed `<Input>` is a void element! You shouldn't add anything inside of it. Also, there isn't an input of type == "select". [input types documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

I would strongly suggest you to switch the conditional rendering to either render `<input type="text" />` or `<select>` elements [Select with option documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using `reactstrap`, so `type='select'` is valid. I managed to achieve this by adding `: undefined` at the end

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I'm using `reactstrap`, so `type='select'` is valid. I managed to achieve this by adding `: undefined`

```
                      {(type === "fixed") ?
                        partOptions.map((opt) =>
                          <option value={opt.code} key={opt.code}>{opt.code}</option>
                        ) : undefined
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to do this. It's not readable code and honestly I am not sure how it would render or hydrate.Looks to me like a bug waiting to happen. This is a use case for conditional rendering.

`const myInput = type === "fixed" ? <Input type="select"> : <Input type="text">`